# mke2fs command options

Tags: linux

I am learning linux and working on ubuntu. I want to know about the parameters changed by user using mke2fs options. tune2fs -l /dev/sdxx is displaying all the parameters like block size, inode size etc. but i want to display only parameters that are changed by user while making filesystem ie. mke2fs -t ext* -b(block size) /dev/sdxx.

Answer (score 0):

You can only take a look at the defaults configured in `/etc/mke2fs.conf` and compare those to the output of `tune2fs`.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/mke2fs.8.html

There is no easy way to get old metadata values for the filesystem. If journaling is enabled it should be possible to find out, but this would require much more effort.

And of course looking at the defaults in the config file does not tell you if and when those were changed too.